# How to add a variable to this?

Tags: php

I am using the following snippet.  How do I add `q=$k` in the `<a href url>`?

```
         <?php 
         echo '<a id=d href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pg='.($s+10).'">Next</a>';

         ?>
```

Comment: `echo '<a id=d href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pg='.($s+10).'&q='.$k.'">Next</a>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
echo '<a id=d href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pg='.($s+10).'&q='.$k.'">Next</a>';
?>
```

Something like that?

Comment: all & signs in links should be &amp; or it rendors a html error!

Comment: This is also missing URL-encoding for the parameters.

Comment: Code simply based on practice used by OP, not best.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<a id=d href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pg=' . ($s+10) . '&q=' . $k . '">Next</a>';
```

Comment: This is missing URL encoding and produces invalid HTML.

Comment: @Kerrek: its more or less taken over from the OP. And URL encoding is not required, wenn the arguments are already valid. Especially integers are safe to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
echo "<a id='d' href='" . html_entities("$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?pg="
     . urlencode($s + 10) . "&q=" . urlencode($k)) . "'>Next</a>";
```

I added suitable escaping for the URL parameter and HTML output: URL encoding for the URL GET parameters, and HTML entity replacement for the entire URL string.